# Constructing groups with certain element orders

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $\omega(G)$ its spectrum (set of orders of elements). I'm wondering if there's a known way to construct a new group $H$ such that for a fixed $n \in \omega(G)$, $\omega(H) = \omega(G) \setminus \{n\}$. By Cauchy's Theorem, this is impossible if $n$ is prime, but I would be interested in any results to this question, especially in the case if $n$ is a product of two primes.

Thanks.

Comment: Have You tried the case $p^2$? I hIt seems to be easier, two primes won't work it seems since you will have elements of order $p$ and $q$ you can construct some $pq$ You need to have at least some $p$ for which $v_p(n) >1$

Comment: Your claim about Cauchy's Theorem is not correct. You can remove primes under suitable conditions. E.g., there is a group whose spectrum is $1$, $3$, and $7$, and you can certainly find groups with spectrum $1,3$ and one with spectrum $1,7$.

Comment: You cannot remove $n$ if there is an $m\in \pi(G)$ such that $n\neq m$ and $n\mid m$.

Comment: @JulesBesson Your claim about two primes is false. See e.g. $S_3$, pr more generally the nonabelian group of order $pq$ when $p\lt q$ and $p\mid q-1$.

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/q/119095

Comment: Sorry I thought $n$ was $\max \pi(n)$ I read too fast!

Comment: It would seem much more common to let $\pi(G)$ be the set of primes that divide the order of $G$), and use $\omega(G)$ to denote the spectrum. Note that the spectrum is completely determined by $\mu(G)$, which is the set of elements that are maximal in $\omega(G)$ under the divisibility partial order, and that for there to be any hope of an $H$ existing with the desired property, you need $n\in\mu(G)$. So you should really be looking at $\mu(G)$ rather than the full spectrum.

Comment: Following Arturo's notation, is it known which downsets (for the divisibility order) occur as $\omega(G)$? ...or, equivalently, which antichains occur as $\mu(G)$? This question seems better.